# Does it require separate condensing units to allow for different rooms to remote control HVAC temperature?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, central-heating, heat-pump

If I want to have a system where one bedroom is blowing hot and another is blowing cold air through remote controlled internal units, do I need multiple outdoor units and ducts?

Imagine you had a kitchen you wanted to cool but a living room you simultaneously wanted to heat and same for bedrooms etc. can this be done in any other way than separate duct/flow rings?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you would need separate units.

There are *multi-head* mini-split HVAC systems. These can work quite well to provide different levels of heating or cooling to different parts of a house. For example, the upstairs may require more cooling than the downstairs in the summer but the downstairs may require more heating than the upstairs in the winter.

However, the idea of a multi-head system is that there are multiple head units instead of a central air handler for more efficient installation (refrigeration lines rather than duct work) and use (heat or cool specific areas as needed rather than the entire house). But like a traditional HVAC system, there is only one outside unit, and a key to modern heat pumps is that they use that same unit for both heating and cooling by reversing the direction of refrigerant flow. That unit simply can't do both heating and cooling at the same time.

Comment: when I go in a hotel and see that some people like it cool but theres a guy with a fever next door with it hot. theoretically each room along a corridor of 10 rooms could be doing hot and cold alternately. does this mean there are 10 outside units?

Comment: Actually, it does! Hotel/motel rooms are a very special case. In every hotel I've been in (not so many, none lately, but a bunch over the years), there is a central HVAC system for the shared areas (lobby, ballroom, restaurant, etc. unless it is a motel where it is just a small front office + hotel rooms) and *every single guest room* has its own small unit in the wall under the window, which can be set to heat or cool. I assume these days they would be heat pumps. In the old days they were probably small air conditioners plus resistance heat. Travelers are very different from home and office

Comment: they come from different environments, used to different temperatures, etc. And especially around change of season there can easily be people in one room who want the heat and the next room want the air conditioning.

Comment: this is very interesting. I have a 600 sqm house built on a hillside where the back of the house can be very cold as it's in the rock and the windows point away from the sun, then the opposite at the front. Also the top floor (of 4 ) gets very hot indeed with air rising. Its very possible that 3 temperatures are needed from the heat pumps at the same time. Some cold some hot. I guess from what you are all saying is that I will need multiple units and circuts of refrigerant? or is there any other way (using heat pumps/ac)?

Comment: That  size house is bigger than you'd handle with a multi head mini split. And really into multi zone size. Two or three full separate units, each either multi head mini split or with ductwork. But 2 or 3 independent systems.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. really helpful!

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way to accomplish this would be to install a few mini split units, one unit for the kitchen, one unit for the living room and one unit with a few zones for the bedrooms. If you wanted the bedrooms to be temperture  controlled separately, they'd each need their own unit. Each unit would require a small condensing unit outside.

Answer (score 2):

In a whole-house system there's typically only one outdoor heat exchanger. That means you can run the system *as a whole* in heating mode or cooling mode, but not both. You can't move heat around inside the house using current technology.

If you have a large enough house to need two outdoor heat exchangers to handle the load and/or distribution (I know friends who do), I *think* that's essentially two separate systems with each handling a subset of the heads. So in theory IF the two rooms you are interested in are on different systems, one could be in heating mode and the other in cooling mode. But realistically, I'm not convinced that's a good idea.

Yes, as Jack suggests, theoretically you could add more outdoor units just for zoning purposes. Assuming you can afford to buy and run them. I'd worry about wasting energy by having them fight each other.

I'd advise considering whether you are ever, realistically, going to need to push the house in both directions at once. I honestly can't think of a case that wouldn't be better served by pushing in one direction and just opening a window for the other.